# How to prevent triangles in OpenGL from rendering on top of triangles in front of themselves

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, shader

I've been working with OpenGL using the OpenTK library for .NET, writing my own engine. I placed 3 different objects, one spinning cube and 2 adjacent cubes. Everything seemed to work fine until I changed the color of the quad on top of the objects.

[image: Rendering Error]

I'm rendering cubes with a green top, on the left the block on the back is being rendered over the block in the front. I can't seem to find out where I'm going wrong with this, when the camera is set to look from the other side it renders correctly.

The following is the related code in classes with irrelevant or unrelated methods, properties and attributes omitted:

*GameState.cs*

```
class GameState : State
{
    // TEMP: Test Block
    SimpleBlock block;

    int i = 0;
    public override void Render()
    {
        base.Render();

        // Set OpenGL Settings
        GL.Viewport(0, 0, 1024, 768);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);

        // Reset the Matrices
        Matrices.ClearMatrices();

        // Set Camera Settings (Field of view in radians)
        Matrices.ProjectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView((float)Math.PI / 2, (1024.0f / 768.0f), 1, 1000);

        // Create the Camera
        // this has to be in reverse
        Matrix4 viewMatrix = Matrix4.CreateRotationX((float)Math.PI/8);
        viewMatrix = viewMatrix.Translate(0, -2, -4);

        // Multiply it with the ModelView (Which at this point is set to a value that we can just use = and it has the same result)
        Matrices.ModelViewMatrix = viewMatrix;

        // Render the Block
        Matrices.Push();

        Matrices.ModelViewMatrix = Matrices.ModelViewMatrix.Translate(2, 0, 0);
        Matrices.ModelViewMatrix = Matrices.ModelViewMatrix.Translate(0.5f, 0, 0.5f);
        Matrices.ModelViewMatrix = Matrices.ModelViewMatrix.Rotate(0, i / 40.0f, 0);
        block.Render();

        Matrices.Pop();

        // Render the Block Again Twice
        Matrices.Push();

        Matrices.ModelViewMatrix = Matrices.ModelViewMatrix.Translate(-2, 0, 0);
        Matrices.ModelViewMatrix = Matrices.ModelViewMatrix.Translate(0.5f, 0, 0.5f);
        block.Render();

        Matrices.ModelViewMatrix = Matrices.ModelViewMatrix.Translate(0, 0, -1);
        block.Render();

        Matrices.Pop();

        // Increment Rotation Test Variable
        i++;
    }
}
```

*SimpleBlock.cs*

```
class SimpleBlock : IBlock
{
    public void Render()
    {
        // Send the Shader Parameters to the GPU
        Shader.Bind();
        Shader.SendMatrices();

        // Begin Rendering the Polys
        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);

        // Front Quad
        Shader.SetColor(Color4.SaddleBrown);
        GL.Normal3(0, 0, 1);
        GLUtils.QuadVertices(
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 1, 0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 0, 0.5f),
            new Vector3( 0.5f, 1, 0.5f),
            new Vector3( 0.5f, 0, 0.5f));

        // Right Quad
        GL.Normal3(1, 0, 0);
        GLUtils.QuadVertices(
            new Vector3(0.5f, 1,  0.5f),
            new Vector3(0.5f, 0,  0.5f),
            new Vector3(0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(0.5f, 0, -0.5f));

        // Back Quad
        GL.Normal3(0, 0, -1);
        GLUtils.QuadVertices(
            new Vector3( 0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
            new Vector3( 0.5f, 0, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 0, -0.5f));

        // Left Quad
        GL.Normal3(-1, 0, 0);
        GLUtils.QuadVertices(
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 0, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 1,  0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 0,  0.5f));

        // Bottom Quad
        GL.Normal3(0, -1, 0);
        GLUtils.QuadVertices(
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 0,  0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 0, -0.5f),
            new Vector3( 0.5f, 0,  0.5f),
            new Vector3( 0.5f, 0, -0.5f));

        // Top Quad
        Shader.SetColor(Color4.Green);
        GL.Normal3(0, 1, 0);
        GLUtils.QuadVertices(
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(-0.5f, 1, 0.5f),
            new Vector3(0.5f, 1, -0.5f),
            new Vector3(0.5f, 1, 0.5f));

        // Done!
        GL.End();
    }
}
```

*BasicFragment.glfs*

```
#version 130

// MultiColor Attribute
in vec4 multiColor;

// Output color
out vec4 gl_FragColor;

void main()
{
    // Set fragment
    gl_FragColor = multiColor;
}
```

*BasicVertex.glvs*

```
#version 130

// Transformation Matrices
uniform mat4 ProjectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 ModelViewMatrix;

// Vertex Position Attribute
in vec3 VertexPos;

// MultiColor Attributes
in vec4 MultiColor;
out vec4 multiColor;

void main()
{
    // Process Colors
    multiColor = MultiColor;

    // Process Vertex
    gl_Position = ProjectionMatrix * ModelViewMatrix * vec4(VertexPos.x, VertexPos.y, VertexPos.z, 1);
}
```

*MainWindow.cs*

```
// Extends OpenTK's GameWindow Class
class MainWindow : GameWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
        : base(1024, 768, new GraphicsMode(32, 0, 0, 4))
    {
        this.Title = "Trench Wars";
        this.WindowBorder = WindowBorder.Fixed;
        this.ClientSize = new Size(1024, 768);

        // Set VSync On
        this.VSync = VSyncMode.Adaptive;
    }

    protected override void OnRenderFrame(FrameEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnRenderFrame(e);

        // Clear Screen
        GL.ClearColor(Color4.CornflowerBlue);
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);

        // Do State-Specific Rendering
        StateEngine.Render();

        // Pull a Wicked Bluffing move in Poker
        GL.Flush();

        // Swap Buffers
        this.SwapBuffers();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the problem more clearly? I don't understand,it looks fine from the image.

Comment: I'm rendering perfect cubes with a green top, on the left the block on the back is being rendered over the block in the front. (I'll add this under it)

Comment: Might be a problem with the framebuffer you are rendering to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you did forget to enable depth testing. `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` before rendering the geometry is your friend (or given the language bindings you're using `GL.Enable(EnableCap.DepthTest);`).

Comment: Added it under "GL.Enable(EnableCap.CullFace);", no change.

Comment: Do I need to do something with depth information in the vertex shader? Because I'm not doing so currently.

Comment: @KelvinBongers: No, nothing in the shaders required. But it might be, that you created your window without a depth component. Also I don't see a call for clearing the framebuffer in your code. Please update your question with the code you use for creating the window, and check, that there's a call to glClear that clears color and depth buffer.

Comment: @KelvinBongers: There's your problem right there: You're requesting 0 depth buffer bits (2nd parameter to Graphics Mode). I suggest you ask for a `GraphicsMode(32, 16, 8, …)` which is the mode most widely supported depth + stencil mode. Also widely supported are 24 depth + 8 stencil and 16 depth + 16 stencil.

Comment: Changed it but it doesn't seem to change the result. I also tried the exact constructor used in the OpenGL3.0 example in OpenTK which also didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @KelvinBongers: Well, I'm out of ideas. The only thing I can tell you is, that you obviously lack depth testing. Either due to a missing depth buffer component or by not properly enabling the depth test. We tried to rule out both and your shaders are in order. The only thing I can think of now are not properly installed OpenGL drivers. The drivers installed by default by Windows Vista and later are lacking proper OpenGL support; so if you didn't install drivers downloaded from the GPU maker's website I'd do this now.

Comment: Running version 314.22 of the NVIDIA GeForce drivers. I could upload the full project folder with all the code.

Comment: Turned out I was missing BOTH GL_DEPTH_TEST AND GraphicsMode(32, 16, 8, …)